# Firebug onload time very high

Tags: javascript, performance, web-applications, browser, firebug

I am currently investigating why my site takes so long to load.
The Firebug net panel tells me this:

7.74s (onload: 16.02s)

What might be causing this huge gap?
What exactly is the browser doing after all resources are loaded until it fires the onload event?

Thanks.

Comment: My guess is it has something to do with either the content of your webpage or the content of your scripts.

Comment: is there any progress in this question ?

Answer (score 4):

It would be difficult to say the cause without a site URL. But you can do the following things at your end.

You can install the following Firefox addons

[YSlow](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/yslow/)

Page Speed addon (check it with Google it is a product from Google itself)

This addons will give you fairly good idea about what causes your issue.

Also have a look the [Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) article from Yahoo! that specifies several points to improve the performance of the website.

Hope this helps.

JP

Answer (score 0):

It's download time vs processing time onload. See also [Timing with the Firebug Net Panel: What is the onload time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263789/timing-with-the-firebug-net-panel-what-is-the-onload-time)

Processing time of your onload scripts is very high, so use a profiler:

Use [the Firefox Profiler tool](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Profiler) to find bottlenecks in your JavaScript code. The Profiler periodically samples the current JavaScript call stack and compiles statistics about the samples.

You can launch the Profiler by selecting "Profiler" from the "Web Developer" menu. You'll find the "Web Developer" menu under the "Tools" menu on Linux and OS X, and directly under the "Firefox" menu on Windows.

Answer (score -1):

If you use the Net panel in Firebug you will get an itemised list of requests and times - you can determine the problem from there.

Ahem...

[image: Firebug Screen grab]