# What do the two times in the summary of Firebug's Net panel mean?

Tags: firebug, onload, network-analysis

I have read in many different places as to what the times shown at the bottom of Firebug's *Net* panel mean and am still a little confused.

A post on a website says:

> The onload time is when your site is done loading everything local to your site (HTML, CSS, Javascript code, images).  The first listed time can be longer than the onload time if you are loading things in from other sites using javascript AJAX reqeusts, videos, widgets from other sites like Facebook or Twitter.

While another answer states this:

> onload time is when the onload event is fired and the other is just initilization

Can someone please elaborate?

[image: Timings within summary of Firebug's *Net* panel]

Comment: The 8.6s is the speed of the page loading (dom). The onload speed would be the dom and all assets being loaded - Images/Css/Js etc.

Answer (score 0):

The first time (in this case 8.6s) means the time elapsed since the start of the first request until the last request finished loading.
*Note: This time can increase when further requests occur later (e.g. through XHRs or dynamically added images, etc.)*

The 'online' time within the brackets (here 8.81s) means the time elapsed since the start of the first request until the page triggered the [`load` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load). See also [Timing with the Firebug Net Panel: What is the onload time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4263789/432681).

I've now updated the [documentation about the *Net* panel request summary](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel#Request_summary) to include this information.

The timing information is also [explained in more detail by the Firebug team leader Jan 'Honza' Odvarko at softwareishard.com](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/firebug-net-panel-timings/).